# luke available version for lucene 4.5

Tags: lucene, luke

I am trying to test an Apache Lucene 4.5 index by navigating and searching and I was looking for the applicable version of Luke to do so, I understood form [Luke website](https://code.google.com/archive/p/luke/) that they use the same version for naming as Lucene, but the latest version they have is 4.0.0ALPAH which can't read my index. I also found [this post in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534392/how-to-open-a-lucene-4-3-index) but I got the same error!

"Invalid directory at the location, check console for more information. Last exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A SPI class of type org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec with name 'Lucene45' does not exist. You need to add the corresponding JAR file supporting this SPI to your classpath.The current classpath supports the following names: [Lucene40, Lucene3x, Lucene41, Lucene42]"

does that mean there is no Luke for Lucene45!
Any hints, please?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/releases

Comment: @femtoRgon million thanks, I tried it and it's working properly